# need a android 4.4.4 webview polyfill for array.prototype.findIndex object[object array] is not a function

Tags: javascript, android, arrays, webview

getting error Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'findIndex' on android webview polyfill(android 4.4.4 webview)

taking mdn polyfill from here(https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex), is not working somehow, not sure why, polyfill is loaded as per script inspection. 
any solutions?
cannot use babel, because need to inject this in webview for some external script.